# removing list elements while traversing the list has unintended effect

Tags: python, list

Here is the simple example

```
>>> list=[(1,2),(3,4),(5,6)]
>>> for i in list:
...     print(i)
...     list.remove(i)
...
(1, 2)
(5, 6)
>>> list
[(3, 4)]
>>>
```

My intention was to print and element and remove it but it seems that the next element gets removed though that is also not true as unprinted element got restored after loop.
Can you explain this behaviour ?
Is this a bug or my method is incorrect ?
Is it possible to do in-place removal without using another copy of list ?
Thanks.

Comment: Yeah . My aim was to understand this behaviour .

Comment: Sure, I thought that was covered somewhere in the [duplicate link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/how-to-remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating), perhaps its not. It does address some of your other concerns though.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6260097/5014455) in the linked duplicate

Comment: "Is it possible to do in-place removal without using another copy of list ?" yes it is, but it is error prone and inefficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
l =[(1,2),(3,4),(5,6)]

for i, v in enumerate(l):
    print (v)
    l[i] = ""

print ([x for x in l if x])
```

Output:

```
(1, 2)
(3, 4)
(5, 6)
[]
```

Briefly, if you remove a list element while you are iterating through, you change the index range. So you remove `(1,2)`, then you skip `(3,4)` cause it is now at the index of removed element `(1,2)`. So second iteration third element `(5,6)`.

So no it is not a bug, and your method is certainly not correct for your needs!

Use enumerate, in my example, or alternatively:

```
for i in range(len(l)):
    print (l[i])
    l[i] = ""

print ([x for x in l if x])
```

In fact, you should never remove an element/index in `list` while iterating through. You can set the value at index to nothing "" then remove the empty elements.

Comment: I definitely agree ```In fact, you should never remove an element/index in list while iterating through.```, but once in a while, I somewhat have to do that but with great caution.

Comment: to Synthase , that was a nice explanation for behaviour . 'enumerate' solution  replaces list element with empty string but list length is still same and list is not empty at the end . An empty list return 'not list' as true. Also, alternatively solution gave error 'TypeError: 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer'

Comment: Yes sorry I corrected for the alternative solution. Range(len(l)) and not range(l)!